# django SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server

Tags: linux, django, smtp

У меня в django такие настройки для почты. Такие настройки на  другом сервере работают, но купил новый для другого проекта и он выдает ошибку SMTP.

[image: Настройки django]

При попытки отправить сообщение выдает ошибку. Мои подозрения что что-то не так с образом linux

[image: Ошибка]

```
File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
main()
File "manage.py", line 18, in main
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/den/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django            /core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/den/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/den/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
File "/home/den/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/den/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/sendtestemail.py", line 29, in handle
send_mail(
File "/home/den/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py", line 61, in send_mail
return mail.send()
File "/home/den/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
File "/home/den/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 102, in send_messages
new_conn_created = self.open()
File "/home/den/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 69, in open
self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 700, in login
raise SMTPNotSupportedError(
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вся проблема была в хостинге именно из-за него не работала почта, помогло когда обратился в тех поддержку.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите вот здесь, может быть поможет:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37224073/smtp-auth-extension-not-supported-by-server

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12030179/issue-sending-email-with-python

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/615819)

Comment: Что за бред? У меня всё нормально было...

Comment: уже перепробовал это и не помогло. Тут проблема в ОС а не в коде.